# X11 Development Libraries

Tags: package-management, libraries

I am new to ubuntu, I am using ubuntu 13.10, and trying to *install* **NS-2**.

During the installation I am facing the following error;

```
X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
```

Then i tried to install

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

This time I am facing the following error;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libx11-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libx11-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I have no idea how to deal it, Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: OP what type of PC you are using ?

Comment: what's the output of `apt-cache xorg-dev libx11-dev`

Comment: I am using DELL Vostro D3550 (Laptop), The output of apt-cache xorg-dev libx11-dev is E: Invalid operation xorg-dev

Answer (score 0):

I am also using  13.10 but its Xubuntu , any way there are the packages you need if you want to install linx11-dev ion 13.10 . try this method .

```
sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0 libpthread-stubs0-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
```

hope that helps.

Comment: This did not worked too, the output is            
Package libx11-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package libpthread-stubs0
E: Unable to locate package libpthread-stubs0-dev
E: Package 'libx11-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libx11-doc
E: Unable to locate package libxau-dev
E: Unable to locate package libxcb1-dev
E: Unable to locate package libxdmcp-dev
E: Unable to locate package x11proto-kb-dev
and so on......